# Firefox freezes when calling function (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, grid

When function `removeCell()` is called, firefox freezes.

I use this function to hide some grid cell's, depending on window width.
Function is called rigth after grid is ready and for every window resizing.
In Chrome and Opera works just fine, but in Firefox it stucks right after first call.

```
function removeCell(){
    headerResize();
    if (($('.section .header .cell:last-child').position().left + $('.section .header .cell:last-child').width()) > 
        $('.section .header').position().left + $('.section .header').width())
    {
        var priority = $body_grid_header[0].priority;
        var index    = 0;

        for(var i in $body_grid_header){
            if(bool($body_grid_header[i].visible) && $body_grid_header[i].priority > priority){
                priority = $body_grid_header[i].priority;
                index    = i;
            }
        }
        $body_grid_header[index].visible = 0;
        $('.grid .header .cell:nth-child('+ (parseInt(index)+2) +')').addClass('hidden');

        $hiddenArray.unshift(index);
        headerResize();
        removeCell();
    }
    else
    {
        //console.log($body_grid_header);
        var firstCell   = $('.grid .header .cell:first-child').width();
        var lastCell    = $('.grid .header .cell:last-child').width();
        var headerWidth = $('.grid .header').width();
        var cellCount   = $('.grid .header .cell').not(':first').not(':last').not('.hidden').length;

        if ((cellCount*100 + 100+firstCell+lastCell < headerWidth) && (cellCount < $body_grid_header.length))
        {
            var index = $hiddenArray[0];
            $hiddenArray.splice(0,1);

            $body_grid_header[index].visible = 1;
            $('.grid .header .cell:nth-child('+ (parseInt(index)+2) +')').removeClass('hidden');
            headerResize();
            removeCell(); //I GUESS IT STUCKS HERE!
        }
    }
}


function headerResize(){
  var firstColl = $('.grid .header .coll:first-child').width();
  var lastColl  = $('.grid .header .coll:last-child').width();
  var headerWidth   = $('.grid .header').width() - firstColl - lastColl;
  var collCount = $('.grid .header .coll').not(':first').not(':last').not('.hidden').length;
  var collWidth     = headerWidth / collCount - 1; //-1 = border-left

  if(collWidth < 100) collWidth = 100;

  $('.section .header .coll').not(':first').not(':last').width(collWidth);
  $('.section .content .coll:not(:first-child)').width(collWidth);
```

}

Comment: Did you debug when the freeze occurs?

Comment: the code you wrote is not recursive....pass the i value to removecell()

Comment: @CodeJack: What `i`? He has recursion that exists in else/if when condition checking fails. What `i` are you referring to?

Comment: ok...my bad...thght he is using {i} for condition...

Comment: It comes out if first and second(inside else) is incorrect.

Comment: This is quite a complicated piece of code @Klemzy. Why don't you tell us what you're trying to do, because it seems you're doing it the way (too complicated)... resizing headers, cells, removing cells, recursing etc... You could also consolidate your selectors... Are you trying to somehow auto-fit columns to acommodate screen width and clip the rest?

Comment: can u try making a fiddle and share the link here..

Comment: ok i'll try. ty for help :>
but it will be difficult

Comment: $('.grid .header').width(); may not be working in firefox...try using ids rather classes....

Comment: @CodeJack: WTF? Why would CSS clas selectors **not** work in Firefox?

Comment: i have replicated some code...i am getting undefined here....and am sure its not bcoz of CSS classes not available..

Answer (score 0):

The code can cause a deadlock in any browser since it boils down to:

```
removeCell() {
     removeCell();
}
```

The only thing that prevents that is the `if()` in the `else` branch:

```
if ((cellCount*100 + 100+firstCell+lastCell < headerWidth) && (cellCount < $body_grid_header.length))
```

If this condition is wrong, you have an endless loop.

Instead of recursive calls, you should really work with a loop and break out of it when all cells have been removed.

Comment: i thght same..but it dont...else has one more condition

Comment: @Klemzy: Check the condition in the else part and run the code in a debugger. For some reason, the second condition is always `true` in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to follow, really hard to test locally :-)

To give it a shot, change

```
if ((cellCount*100 + 100+firstCell+lastCell < headerWidth) && (cellCount < $body_grid_header.length))
```

to

```
if ((cellCount*100 + 100+firstCell+lastCell < headerWidth) && $hiddenArray.length)
```

Hope it works...

Comment: no, it doesn't work...:/
there is no freezing in that case, but now it doesnt show back cells when there is enough space...:/

Comment: shame. maybe you could set up a jsfiddle, then it's more easy to help you